# Matlab - Display common features

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm working on a project for university, which currently takes a reference image of a coin and produces 100 drawn images of it, with different brightness settings to capture as many features as possible.

So for example, here is a reference coin and just a select images that the application has produced.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What I want to achieve is an addition to my current application, to go through these 100 drawn images and automatically pick out the dominant features that appear multiple times.

**How it could work**

- Application grabs the 100 reference images.
- If a line on the image is repeated/displayed 40/50 times, add it to the final drawn image.
- At the end, the final drawn image is generated, this time displaying all the dominant features of this coin.

I hope I've made it clear what I have in my head, but since I'm a newcomer with Matlab, I'm completely unsure on how to detect repetitive features on multiple images like I've shown above. If anyone can point me in the right direction or illustrate a solution, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you need more help? Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This should be straightforward if you do it with pixels.

If you have 100 binary images, lets assume in a 3D matrix `bwImg(N,P,100)`

You just need to add them

```
sumbwImg=sum(bwImg,3);
```

And then binarize them again on the range you want, e.g. 40 times.

```
repeated=sumbwImg>=40;
```

---

If your images are saved in different files (I hope you do not have 100 variables.....) then create a 3D matrix as:

```
for ii=1:100
    img=load('image_ii.png'); %wherever its saved
    bwImg(:,:,ii)=img;
end
```

Comment: I've not used a 3D matrix before, so how would I go about adding all the images into there?

Comment: @iBenParry The same way you woudl add info to a 2D matrix